# How can I extract the hex values from the text file using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, hex

I am in need of extracting the hexadecimal values from a textfile using a SQL Server stored procedure.

I wrote the procedure to give the inputs (hex value - `068F 015A 0000 01A7 69 019A 6B 00F1 6A`) manually, but I need to pass in a **filename** as input. From that file I have to **extract the content**.

My file content looks something like this :

```
V( 068F 015A 0000 01A7 69 019A 6B 00F1 6A )
V( 0665 0158 0000 01A8 68 0186 6B 00EE 6A )
V( 0687 017A 0000 01C3 67 018A 69 00F9 69 )
V( 067F 0171 0000 01AF 66 01A4 68 00F6 67 )
V( 06C2 0162 0000 01AA 64 0191 66 0150 65 )
V( 07E7 0163 0000 01B3 62 0195 64 0213 64 )
V( 0876 0166 0000 01CA 60 0214 62 01EF 62 )
V( 0BA1 015F 0000 021B 5E 039C 60 024B 60 )
V( 0DC9 014D 0007 01A2 5B 0426 5C 0407 5D )
V( 0E30 0140 000A 013E 5B 04A2 5B 043A 5C )
V( 0E6B 0130 000B 013C 5A 04B4 5A 046D 5B )
V( 0DDC 0150 0011 015A 58 052A 59 0399 5A )
V( 0C1C 0164 0001 013E 55 0456 56 03A4 56 )
V( 0CF0 02EA 0000 01B0 55 0534 56 0338 57 )
V( 0B86 03A1 0000 01D3 57 0461 58 02D6 59 )
V( 0950 0236 0000 013F 59 03A1 5A 0226 5A )
V( 0847 0279 0000 00CC 59 03A7 59 01E1 5B )
V( 0734 0203 0000 0078 5B 037D 5B 0156 5D )
V( 075D 038B 0000 00DD 5E 0306 5E 01E3 60 )
V( 073E 02C6 0000 0117 61 028A 62 0191 63 )
V( 0606 0183 0000 0095 62 01C8 63 01A7 64 )
V( 0793 0310 0000 00D4 5F 02CF 5F 020A 61 )
V( 07C2 03C0 0000 011D 5D 0301 5D 0211 5E )
V( 080A 043B 0000 0170 5E 031C 5E 01E6 60 )
V( 06FD 041C 0000 0129 60 02B1 60 01D5 61 )
V( 05D2 03A3 0000 0139 62 014E 62 0238 63 )
V( 06CC 046E 0000 0153 62 0205 62 0240 63 )
```

Please help me..

I tried like this for the single Hex value

```
set @sting='068F 015A 0000 01A7 69 019A 6B 00F1 6A'
    set @string=replace(@string,' ',',')
    SET @Delimiter = ','
    SET @string = @string + @Delimiter
    SET @Pos = charindex(@Delimiter,@string)
    while(@Pos <> 0)
    begin
    select @mid ='0x'+substring(@string,1,@Pos - 1)
    set @query='select convert(int,'+@mid+')' 
    insert @word execute (@query)
    select @value=value from @word 
    SET @string = substring(@string,@pos+1,len(@string))
    SET @pos = charindex(@Delimiter,@string)
    end
```

Thank you,

Comment: **Show us** what you've tried so far!

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be? N rows of one column `binary(15)`?

Comment: I need to know how to fetch those values as 068F 015A 0000 01A7 69 019A 6B 00F1 6A from the file directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to read the content from the textfile.

```
alter PROCEDURE ReadFromTextFile

@FileName VARCHAR (1024)

AS
DECLARE @OLEResult INT
DECLARE @FS INT
DECLARE @FileID INT
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR (8000)
drop table hex_temp
create table hex_temp (id int identity(1,1),value varchar(max))
-- Create an instance of the file system object
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FS OUT
IF @OLEResult <> 0
BEGIN
PRINT 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'
PRINT 'Error code: ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, @OLEResult)
END

-- Open the text file for reading
EXEC @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FS, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @FileName, 1, 1
IF @OLEResult <> 0
BEGIN
PRINT 'OpenTextFile'
PRINT 'Error code: ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, @OLEResult)
END

-- Read the first line into the @Message variable
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'ReadLine', @Message OUT

-- Keep looping through until the @OLEResult variable is < 0; this indicates that the end of the file has been reached.
WHILE @OLEResult >= 0
BEGIN
insert into hex_temp(value) values (@Message)
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'ReadLine', @Message OUT
END

EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FileID
EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OADestroy @FS
```